# webpack historyApiFallback не работает

Tags: javascript, webpack, html5-history-api

Есть основная страница index.html, мне нужно перекидывать на неё пользователя со страниц типа `domain/pageName` и `domain/chats/123`

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app/index.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'index.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
    },
    devServer: {
      overlay: true,
      historyApiFallback: {
        rewrites: [{
            from: /^\/(.*)/i,
            to: 'https://www.youtube.com/'
          },
          {
            from: /^\/chats\/(.*)/i,
            to: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgtQIBOy5Ko&t=2562s'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    //......
    // ВЫРЕЗАНО
    //......
}
```

В примере использовал ютуб вместо index.html

Итак, если у меня url типа domain/pageName, то меня перекидывает на index.html (не на ютуб) почему не понимаю (даже если заменить первую регулярку на совершенно другую всё равно перекидывает на index.html)
Второй редирект вообще не работает
И вот такие ошибки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В принципе можно со всех url перенаправлять пользователя на index.html

Comment: Никто до сих пор не ответил??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я всё-таки нашел ответ на свой вопрос, хотя я Хз как это влияет на history API

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  devServer: {
    overlay: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
}
```

Я убрал все редиректы и оставил `historyApiFallback` ппросто на `true`

Потом я добавил `publicPath: '/'`
И оно чудесным образом заработало